# Transition animation applying only to activity and not to menu fragment

Tags: android

I have a fragment which I use as a menu bar on top of the screen to switch between activities and show which activity is currently open by highlighting its icon. It is hardcoded through XML in 4 of my activies.  These activities are represented by icons and each icon has an onclicklistener which loads the appropriate activity when clicked. My question is, when I have a transition to switch between activities, is it possible to keep the menu bar in place and only switch the content of the activity like in Vine or YikYak with the sliding model. If this requires recoding all 4 activities I won't do it as it's only for eye-candy however I would like to know how difficult and time consuming this would be.

Answer (score 0):

For the short answer, by replacing the Activity, you replace the entire UI, so no, it isn't possible.

The long answer is this:

Vine and YikYak don't replace the entire Activity, only the Fragments. So if you had a layout structured like this:

```
Activity
 |-- Menu Bar
 |-- Content
```

then YikYak and Vine only replace the Content Fragment, not the Activity. This is essentially what Google recommends with the DrawerFragment. In order to do this you would have to rewrite your entire app to make use of Fragment changes rather than Activity changes. I would recommend doing this despite the extra work, as its one of the main benefits to using Fragments at all.

Comment: My layout is currently structured like this : 
`Activity 
   ---- Menu Bar Fragment
   ---- Content within activity, not within fragment`